# Java 9 Module System

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

I'm trying to learn the new module features of java 9. I don't think I'm doing the requires/exports thing right because intelliJ is giving me red text on my imports unless I add the dependencies in the `project structure` window, which I'm pretty sure is the wrong way to go. Below is my file structure

```
app  
--src  
----start  
------main.java  
----module-info.java  

hello  
--src  
----hello  
------Hello.java  
----module-info.java
```

This is the module-info for `app`:

```
module name {
    requires hello;
}
```

This is the module-info for `hello`:

```
module name {
    exports hello;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Choosing `name` as the name for both Java modules isn't a good idea (it might not compile if you try to require a different Java module with the same name).

It also seems that you're attempting to require a **package** `hello`, but you should be requiring the **other Java module**.  For this reason, I recommend you rewrite the `module-info.java` file in `app` to be the following:

```
module app {
    requires hello;
}
```

And rewrite the `module-info.java` file in `hello` to be the following:

```
module hello {
    exports hello;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much